# Extjs adding a listener to tree panel returns Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scope' of undefined

Tags: extjs

I am trying to add a selection change listener on a tree panel but i get the following error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scope' of undefined

code follows:
xxx.view.trees.MainTree.js

```
extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',

requires: [

    'xxx.store.TreeStore'

],
xtype: 'main-tree',


height: 400,
width: 350,
title: 'Tree',
useArrows: true,

initComponent: function() {
    Ext.apply(this, {
        store: new xxx.store.TreeStore(),
        listeners:{

            selectionchange:this.onClick
        }
    });
    this.callParent();
}
```

xxx.store.Treestore

```
extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',


proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'resources/tree-nodes.json'
},

root: {
    text: 'Contacts',
    id: 'src',
    expanded: true
},
```

xxx.view.MainController.js

```
  onClick: function (sender, selected, eOpts) {

}
```

Comment: Use `on` to attach listeners.

Comment: What version of ExtJS are you using?

Comment: @ DrakeES sorry 5.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
selectionchange:this.onClick
```

with:

```
selectionchange: 'onClick'
```